# Spring 4 conditional - Accessing a resource

Tags: java, spring-4

Doing my first steps with spring 4 I tried the @Conditional annotation following [this article](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/10/spring-4-conditional.html/comment-page-1/#comment-18295).

My problem - 
I would like to get access to a classpath resource (basically a properties file) from method matches in class OnSystemPropertyCondition.

To do that currently I'm loading the required properties file from the matches method every time it is invoked (which means for every class annotated with the ConditionalOnSystemProperty annotation).
This is a bit ugly. I thought that an elegant solution would be to simply autowire my resource or some properties (using the @Value annotation) but this can't be done since this class gets instanciated before the beans.

Any suggestions than can help me avoid reload this resource again and again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The single method of the annotation gets in its signature the input param `ConditionContext context`. You can obtain an [Environment](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/env/Environment.html) from the context by calling `context.getEnvironment()`. The environment gives access to all my resources (look at [this](http://blog.jamesdbloom.com/UsingPropertySourceAndEnvironment.html) to see how to get access to your resources via spring environment).